# PHP Script not executing - Login Form Capture

Tags: php, css, html

This is the html code for the login form:

```
<div id="container">
         <form id= 'login' method="post" action="login.php" accept- charset='UTF-8'>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">

            <div id="lower">
                <input type="checkbox"><label class="check"    for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div><!--/ lower-->

        </form>
    </div><!--/ container-->
```

This is the php script to save the form data:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$fp = fopen("data.txt","a");
$savestring = $username.",".$password."n";
fwrite($fp,$savestring);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

However, upon filling out the information in the form I am redirected to a webpage simply showing the php script. Nothing is actually 'executed'.

Comment: Are you executing on a PHP enabled webserver or using `file:///` protocol?

Comment: try a very basic `<?php echo 'hello world!'; ?>`

Comment: @PraveenKumar it is local, no web server is used

Comment: Then it will **NOT** work! You cannot execute a .NET program using Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

> However, upon filling out the information in the form I am redirected to a webpage simply showing the php script.

You must execute your code on a **Web Server** with parsing PHP Enabled. Examples include:

- [W] Microsoft IIS Server with PHP ISAPI Plugin.
- [W/L/M] Apache HTTP Server with PHP.
- [W/L/M] NginX Server with PHP.
- [W/L/M] LigHTTPD Server with PHP.

Bundles:

- [W/M] [ApacheFriends XAMPP][1](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)
- [W] [WAMP Server][2](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
- [W/M] [MAMP / MAMP Pro][3](https://www.mamp.info/)
- [W/L/M] [AMPPS][4](http://www.ampps.com/)

*W: Windows / L: Linux / M: Mac*

Comment: I am executing it locally, I want this webpage to load up upon the user connecting to my WiFi hotspot.

Comment: I am telling you again, like how Notepad doesn't know to execute .NET, you **cannot** execute a server side script on the browser. It **has** to be handled by the Server.

Comment: Okay so if I setup an apache server it will work then?

Comment: Yes yes, it does. Have a look at the bundles I have given in my answer. They are best if you don't know to set up individually.